# Running a function if dtype is equal to object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am experimenting with some functions in pandas and I am trying to run test() on a data frame and have test() create dummy variables if the data frame contains dtypes that are equal to objects.

I am able to get the function to print out a np arrary with the dummy vars, but I cant seem to get it to overwrite the df that I read into test()

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/communities/communities.data'
    df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=',', header=0, names=names, na_values='?')
    df.head(2) 

def test(data):
    for i in data.columns:
        if data[i].dtype == 'object':
            list_ = list(data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)
            #print list_
            data = pd.get_dummies(data, prefix=list_)
            return data
#test(df)
#df = df.apply(test, axis =1)
df.apply(test)
#df.head(2)
```

> AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'",
>   u'occurred at index state')

Comment: What is your expected output from `data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns`?

Comment: a list of columns that dtype are 'object'

Comment: Isn't that what `data.select_dtypes(include=['object'])` would yield? I believe there's even a `tolist`method on Series, so you could try `data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).tolist()`.

Comment: but then I pass the data.select_dtypes(include=['object']) as a var 'list_'to pd.get_dummies(data, prefix=list_). I'm confused on how to have data overwrite the df that was placed in test(data)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken, forget my comment from before :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100992/discussion-between-karlson-and-icomefromchaos).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that the function passed to `DataFrame.apply` expects a `Series` as its argument, not a `DataFrame`. Rewrite `test` as

```
def test(data):
    list_ = list(data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)
    data = pd.get_dummies(data, prefix=list_)
    return data
```

and then call

```
test(df)
```

This should give you a brand new `DataFrame` with all columns of dtype 'object'.